# multiple values for argument on_delete

Tags: python, django

When I run this code I get an error which looks like the text below and I actually have no clue on how to fix it because I'm a newbie, someone on here must know how to fix this, was following a tutorial on YouTube and started making some of my own changes.

> File "C:\Users\kristian\webdevelopment\websida\ecommerce\store\models.py", line 131, in OrderItem
> product = models.ForeignKey(Product_main, Product_Diverse, Product_Teknikprylar, Product_Verktyg, Product_Maskiner, Product_Guldfynd, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
> TypeError: **init**() got multiple values for argument 'on_delete'

```
class Product_Diverse(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url




class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    date_order = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product_main, Product_Diverse, Product_Teknikprylar, Product_Verktyg, Product_Maskiner, Product_Guldfynd, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: You can not make a `ForeignKey` like `ForeignKey(Product_main, Product_Diverse, Product_Teknikpry,...)`. The second parameter is `on_delete`, not an extra model you can refer to.

Answer (score 2):

The [constructor of a **`ForeignKey`** object [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L790-L792), is defined as:

> ```
>     def __init__(self, to, on_delete, related_name=None, related_query_name=None,
>                  limit_choices_to=None, parent_link=False, to_field=None,
>                  db_constraint=True, **kwargs):
> ```

so the second position parameter is `on_delete`, the third position parameter is `related_name`, etc.

If you write:

```
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product_main,          # to
        Product_Diverse,       # on_delete
        Product_Teknikprylar,  # related_name
        Product_Verktyg,       # related_query_name
        Product_Maskiner,      # limit_choices_to
        Product_Guldfynd,      # parent_link
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
```

you thus pass values for parameters like `on_delete`, etc. Not to other things a `ForeignKey` can refer to.

A `ForeignKey` can not refer to multiple models. A `ForeignKey` can only refer to *one* model. You might want to make a parent model `Product` and use [*model inheritance* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance). You can also make use of [*generic relations* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) if you need this, but there are several disadvantages (like *referential integrity*).

Comment: Helped me having `ForeignKey('Ref_dModel'. model.SET_NULL, ..., on_delete=model.SET_NULL)` by changing to only `ForeignKey('Ref_dModel'. model.SET_NULL, ..., )` (dropping either the kwarg or the positional second arg.